# How to select a loaded image and insert it into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an image that is loaded when the site is called.

```
<img id="some_Image" src="some_source">
```

Now I want to reuse that image and **NOT** request it again from `"some_source"`. (Because it has to be computed and I do not want to recalculate it). I want that image later to be displayed in some JQuery dialog. I know the existance of `append` and `prepend` functions, but reading the documentation it seems like I have to insert a whole image tag as an argument, which results in requesting the image again. (if the browser doesn't cache the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the [jQuery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

it is supposed to work with images as well, if the image has been loaded by the browser its supposed to reuse it.

EDIT:

```
$( "#some_image" ).clone().appendTo( "#some_div" );
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It worked nice! The `clone`-function was what I was searching for. Here the code: `$( "#some_image" ).clone().appendTo( "#some_div" );` . Maybe you can add it to your answer, so anybody who has a similar problem will find it more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all browsers cache as much as they can (js, css, images). This way, the moment your image is loaded you can create a new `<img>` tag with the same source path and the browser will use its local cached file.